# Is there a way to access control properties within custom user control from Designer using c# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have here some custom user control with `DataGridView` in it, now when i Implement my user control to some form I want to be able to access `DataGridView` properties within designer, is this possible?

**This is my user control**

```
   public partial class MyUserControlTest01 : UserControl
    {

        // my way to accsses DataGridView 
        // 
        public DataGridView Dtv_userControl
        {
            get { return myUserControl_datagridView; }
            set { myUserControl_datagridView = value; }
        }


        public MyUserControlTest01()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
```

So when i implement this user control to some Form, I can access `DataGridView` properties from code, but i want to do it from Designer.

Hope my question is clear,
any suggestion is helpful.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these annotations over your DataGridView-Property

```
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("*Any category you want*")]
public DataGridView Dtv_userControl
{
   get { return myUserControl_datagridView; }
   set { myUserControl_datagridView = value; }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, can you tell me what is category annotation for?

Comment: If you set the property ordering to "Categorized" in your designer, your dgv will be found beneath the given string of your "Category"